# Set option value as option Class/ID jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to setup the option value as option id or class within the dropdown list. I have a dropdown

```
<select id="test">
<option value="tes1">Tes1</option>
<option value="tes2">Tes2</option>
<option value="tes3">Tes3</option>
</select>
```

I want to make the dropdown like this

```
<select id="test">
    <option value="tes1" id="tes1">Tes1</option>
    <option value="tes2" id="tes2">Tes2</option>
    <option value="tes3" id="tes3">Tes3</option>
    </select>
```

I am trying to setup the values of the options as ID/Class.

Comment: Why would you want do this? (-> [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com))

Comment: Based on the id's later on I want to change the order of the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You can set attributes using `.attr()` in juery

```js
$('option').each(function(){
$(this).attr('id',$(this).val())
$(this).attr('class',$(this).val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test">
<option value="tes1">Tes1</option>
<option value="tes2">Tes2</option>
<option value="tes3">Tes3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That's a really "expensive" way of doing this: `$("option").each(function() { this.id = this.value; this.className = this.value; })`

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```js
$("#test > option").each(function() {
  $(this).attr('id',this.text.toLowerCase());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test">
  <option value="tes1">Tes1</option>
  <option value="tes2">Tes2</option>
  <option value="tes3">Tes3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using jQuery's [`.prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) method.

```js
$("#test option").each(function(){
    $(this).prop("id", $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="test">
    <option value="tes1">Tes1</option>
    <option value="tes2">Tes2</option>
    <option value="tes3">Tes3</option>
</select>
```